# Bash conditional expression not working

Tags: bash

```
$ echo $(adb shell getprop service.adb.root)
1
$ while [[ $(adb shell getprop service.adb.root) != "1" ]]; do echo -n .; done
.........^C
```

`[[ "1" != "1" ]]` should be `false` and the `while` loop should not run. But, it runs forever. What's the reason and the fix?

I am trying to write a loop that will wait until the adbd daemon on the connected Android device restarts as root.

Comment: Can you show output of: `echo $(adb shell getprop service.adb.root) | cat -vte`

Comment: make that `adb shell getprop service.adb.root | cat -vte`

Comment: The correct loop is as follows. When adb is restarting on the device (as root), the adb shell command will print errors. This loop discards the error messages. `while [[ $(adb shell getprop service.adb.root 2> /dev/null) != $'1\r' ]]; do echo -n .; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result from the `getprop` command contains a carriage return (ASCII `0x0d`).  Since you're making a string -- not a numeric -- comparison, you're effectively running:

```
[[ "1" != "1\r" ]]
```

The simplist way to fix this is to explicitly strip the carriage return:

```
x=$(adb shell getprop  service.adb.root | tr -d '\015')
```

Now your comparison should work.

You can see exactly what `getprop` is returning by running:

```
$ adb shell getprop  service.adb.root | od -c
0000000   1  \r  \n
0000003
```

Comment: I am accepting this answer since it explains the problem, but I like the simpler fix provided by anubhava.

Answer (score 2):

Since output of adb command has trailing `\r` you can use this `while loop` instead:

```
while [[ $(adb shell getprop service.adb.root) != $'1\r' ]]; do echo -n .; done
```

i.e. compare numbers not strings.

Comment: Why? What's the reason?

Comment: I like your fix, but accepted the other answer because it explained the problem. My low rep does not allow me to vote for your answer.

Comment: This is to make sure any string starting with "1" is matched as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: Even simpler, use `(( $(adb ...) != 1 ))`; the arithmetic context will cause the trailing non-digits from the output of `adb` to be ignored.

Comment: @chepner I had tried arithmetic evaluation first and it does not work. `$ while (( $(adb shell getprop service.adb.root) != 1 )); do echo -n .; done != 1 ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "`

Comment: @apricot Sorry, you're right. I had several little problems with my test that made it appear to work.

Comment: `1*` is overly broad: it will return true if the abd command returns "12". Since this is bash, you can check for a CR directly: `[[ $out == $'1\r' ]]`

Comment: Recommend rewording, the "might" qualifier in your answer doesn't apply.